# PHP and MySQL: Order by most recent date and limit 10

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, limit, querying

I am building a notes system on my site and I've got to the stage where users can post notes into the MySQL database using PHP and then PHP prints them out on a page. However, when they print/echo out, the oldest one appears first but I want the most recent first. I also want them to be limited to 10, so only 10 appear on the page. Here is my PHP code, your help will be much appreciated:

```
// initialize some variables
$notedisplaylist = "";
$myObject = "";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_author_id='$u_id' ORDER BY         date_time");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $note_title = $row["note_title"];
  $note_body = $row["note_body"];
  $date = $row["date_time"];
  $notedisplaylist .= '<h2>' . $note_title . '</h2><br /><p>' . $note_body . '</p><hr /><p>Noted: ' . $date . '</p><hr /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This should do it :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_author_id='$u_id' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 0, 10");
```

Answer (score 10):

use:

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_author_id='$u_id' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 10
```

DESC : descending order ( from newest to oldest )
LIMIT 10: first 10 records found.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_author_id='$u_id' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 10");
```

For a more detailed explanation on `ORDER` and `LIMIT`, visit the MySQL doc's articles about [sorting rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) and the basic [select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) (look for a bullet describing `LIMIT`).

Answer (score 6):

give like

```
 ORDER BY date_time DESC
```

otherwise you are sorting them in ascending order.. thats why older ones come first

Answer (score 5):

Do this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_author_id='$u_id' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 0, 10");
```

Answer (score 0):

If in case you want your LIMIT to be a variable, here I named it $limit:

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY input_date DESC LIMIT 0, $limit";
```